# Can I use StackExchange.Redis to store a Null value in Redis?

Tags: stackexchange.redis

Is there any way to use the StackExchange.Redis client to store a Null value in Redis?

If you use `IDatabase.StringGet(key)` then the returning of Null is used to signify that there "was no result".  Therefore if you use `IDatabase.StringSet(key, null)` then the result is you don't know whether there is a **Null** value or **No** value!

Is there any mechanism for catering for this? - i.e. you want to cache a ***negative***.

I was rather hoping to avoid any nasty sentinel values (like `value ?? new byte[] {1}`) that could later cause issues if a value happened to match!

I had a look at [`RedisValue.Null`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisValue.cs) but that just yields a Null which has the same issues as above.

Comment: What is your use case? Why would you like to store null against a key?

Comment: My cache layer reduces calls to the DB.  There are times when I have no results from my DB so I would like to cache that result so that next time calls hit the cache only (with a result of "data empty").  At the moment, the null response indicates that the cache didn't have a result, so I end up going to the DB to then fetch the "nothing" result.

Answer (score 4):

This is usual dilemma with nulls. We had similar situations and here is how we dealt with them:

1. We retrieved list of dates from backend system and stored them in cache. DAL class returned `null` if no dates were retrieved and threw an exception in case of error/timeout communicating with backend system. In order to cache null value, we replaced null with empty list - which still signified that there was no date available.
2. We used to store users preference as a string in backend. A `null` value signified that user had not set preference. To cache this, we cached special string value that would never occur in the use case - something like **NO PREFERENCE**.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a proxy pattern to reduce calls to the database. The only reasonable way I found was to store an empty byte array in Redis.

```
byte[] array = new byte[0];
IDatabase.StringSet(key, array)
```

When querying Redis you can use `value.IsNull` to check if byte array is empty or not.

This way seems preferable to storing `0`, `""` or any other arbitrary value.